# Swift println() does not display anything in a let in

Tags: swift, println

Why I can't see the output of `println()` when it is called inside an `in` statement? And how I can see this output in Xcode?

I have done this dummy test code:

```
public class TestClass {
    public var testType: String = ""

    public func test(test:((TestClass) -> Void)!){
        testType = "TEST"
    }
}

var request = TestClass()
request.test({(response: TestClass) in
    println("Test: \(response.testType)")
})
```

Comment: Because you don't call the closure anywhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example you are calling method `test()` takes as parameter function of type `TestClass -> Void`. However, in implementation of `test()` method you never call passed function, thus `println()` is never executed.

You could try

```
public func test(testFunction:((TestClass) -> Void)!){
    testType = "TEST"
    testFunction(self)
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to have this result without modifying test() function ?

Comment: I changed the name of function passed as parameter for clarity - you had two things with the same name. If you are asking whether its possible to execute `testFunction` without  calling it inside `TestClass.test`, than answer is no.

Answer (score 0):

You don't call the closure inside TestClass.test

Change it to

```
public func test(test:((TestClass) -> Void)!){
    testType = "TEST"
    test(self)
}
```